# Define a COM smarter pointer as a member in header file?

Tags: c++, com, header-files, smart-pointers, class-members

I am wondering how to define a COM smart pointer in a header file as a class member? Here is what did:

- In .cpp file, I have:

  ```
  long MyClass:MyFun(long &deviceCount)
  {
      RESULT h = CoInitialize(NULL);
      MyComPtr ptr(__uuidof(MyComClass));

      if(deviceCount > 0)
          ptr->Connect();
  }
  ```

But since other functions need to use ptr, I am thinking about changing it to a class member and define it in the header file, something like this:

- In .h file:

  ```
  MyComPtr _ptr;
  ```
- then in .cpp file, I have:

  ```
  _ptr(__uuidof(MyComClass));
  ```

But the compile did not go through, it says "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument". I am very confused how I can implement this. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** So to use initilizer list, it shoule be something like this?

```
MyClass:MyClass() : _ptr(new MyCom)
{
    _ptr(__uuidof(MyComClass));
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the term *"initializer list"* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: No I am not, but I would like to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer list is called at construction time to set variables that would otherwise be const. It's commonly used for const variables, references, etc. I don't actually know COM, but if the smart pointer has similar mechanics to a reference (i.e. once set it cannot be retargeted) then it will have to be initialized at construction time, using an initializer list.

```
Constructor() : _Ptr(new MyComObject)
{
 // Other constructor stuff here
}
```

The syntax is probably wrong - as I said, I don't know COM - but this might be helpful?

EDIT:

Assuming you have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(); // constructor
    MyComPtr _ptr;
};
```

Then in your .cpp, define your constructor like this :

```
MyClass::MyClass() : _ptr(__uuidof(MyComClass)
{
   // rest of constructor code
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more code, especially linking your solution to my case? It is hard for me to figure out the connection betwee your code and mine. Thanks.

Comment: And where do I put in the __uuidof(MyComClass) stuff?

Comment: Without seeing your class, I can't really give that much more information. Also I am reluctant to say too much, as I could be totally wrong, but basically I am assuming you have this :

http://pastebin.com/SA8WUgJ0

Ultimately, as I said before, I don't know for sure. I just figured I'd answer what initializer lists were, as it could be the fix you're looking for.